# iTextSharp - Generate PDF file - The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required

Tags: c#, authentication, proxy, itext, html-to-pdf

I am facing proxy authentication issue on my below code snipplet.

```
file = [FILEPATH]
htmlData = [HTML CONTENTS]

System.IO.StringReader objReader = default(System.IO.StringReader);
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = default(HTMLWorker);

objReader = new System.IO.StringReader(htmlData);
FileStream fsTest = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fsTest);

pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(objReader);
pdfDoc.Close();
```

I am not sure weather it is iTextSharp issue or I need to do some authentication at code level?
Please suggest.

Detailed error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. || System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required. at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url) at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, Dictionary`2 h) at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader) at AppWeb.AssetActions.GeneratePDFFromHTML(String htmlData, String file) || at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() at iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url) at iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.HTMLWorker.StartElement(String tag, Dictionary`2 h) at iTextSharp.text.xml.simpleparser.SimpleXMLParser.Go(TextReader reader) at.
```

Comment: Check your [FILEPATH] variable. Is it a remote location such as "\\SERVER1\PATH1" that might need an authentication ?

Comment: Yes, I checked it and not remote path. It is Server.Mappath(...)

Comment: But whatever the value is, did you make sure that it refers to the local path (like C:\ or D:\\)? If not, then make it write the value on the response stream and check it out.

Comment: Cause, I cannot think of any other portion of your code trying to access a remote path and getting a proxy-auth error. Btw are you sure that one of these lines in your code are causing this problem and other portions of your code are working correctly?

Comment: Yes, I tried with creating text (.txt) file on same path for writing error log and it is working fine.

Comment: Edited: Detail error path added.

Comment: In that case, you should check your html data. My feeling is that the html data might be containing some external links and getting called when you say htmlparser.Parse()

Comment: So, get your html data, find those links and try to access some of them manually in your browser.

Comment: Even more specific as the error occurs during `iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Uri url)`: There seems to be an image requested from some site routed via the Proxy in question.

Comment: hmm, let me check html.

Comment: Yup, after looking at GetInstance(Uri url) only, I suggested looking into htmldata :-)

Comment: Yes, It is due to image path given as <%= %> = I removed that part and it is now working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have commented, you should check each url within the htmlData string. You need to make sure each url is accessible without any proxy errors by your .NET assembly.
Also search for any parsing tags used by template engines. Here are some that come to my mind:

```
<? ?> - php
<?php ?> - php
<?= ?> - php
<% %> - asp, asp.net, php
<%= %> - asp, asp.net, php
<< >> - webapp2
```